# Foswiki Installation on Win Server 2012 and IIS?

Tags: iis, foswiki

Has anyone had experience installing Foswiki on windows in the past couple of years? It unfortunately seems that all the guides are extremely old and vague. 
The setup on my target machine is Windows Server 2012, Activestate Perl, and IIS 10. The machine is a company server, so I cannot change the setup or install another web server like Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't think that these are suitable preconditions: there are too many gotchas, too few people that ever went that route, it will cost you lots of efforts and the result will be inferior. There are two alternatives: (1) convert the machine to a Linux server or (2) grab the VM from https://foswiki.org/Download/FoswikiRelease02x01x04 with a pre-installed Foswiki ready to go.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I DID manage to get it working using version 1.1.10, I didn't even set up some permissions and it worked surprisingly. I tried 2.1.2, 2.1.1 with no luck, perhaps 2.0 would work but I didn't have the patience to try more of them. In this ticket https://foswiki.org/Tasks/Item14515, 'Foswiki::Aux::MuteOut' is using a reserved keyword for Windows, hence why 2.1.4 does not work.

Comment: If that only was all of your problems. Foswiki 2.1.4 is quite important as a release. It fixes a couple of security issues found by Intel Corp, as well as makes Foswiki compatible with newer perls. You definitely need an up to date perl such as 5.26.1 as this fixes CVE-2017-12883 and CVE-2017-12837.